# Can't install package libclassicclient

Tags: apt, usb, package-management, card-reader

This is the output of "sudo apt-get install libclassicclient":

```
user1@laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install libclassicclient
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
libclassicclient is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up libclassicclient (6.1.0-b08) ...
WARNING: libsqlite3.so could not be found. Creating symbolic link...
/usr/lib /
ls: cannot access libsqlite3.so: Too many levels of symbolic links
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./libsqlite3.so’: File exists
/
Creating symbolic link done.
 * Stopping the hotplug events dispatcher udevd                                                                                          [ OK ]
dpkg: error processing libclassicclient (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libclassicclient
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions?

PS:

```
user1@laptop:/lib$ ldconfig -p | grep classic

user1@laptop:/lib$
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to install the packages that you haven't upgraded yet and try again?

Comment: Also try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install -f` because this could be a dependency problem (dpkg error involved)

Comment: Remove and then reinstall the package `libclassicclient`

Answer (score 0):

You can `--force-all` the installation, (and `libclassicclient` will work) but after this installation, you will have dkpg message :

```
dpkg: error processing package libclassicclient
```

each time you will install a new package ...

To remove this warning just remove the file :

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libclassicclient.postinst
```

May be, you will need to create the simlink by hand. To do so, cd to `/usr/lib`.
If a link `libsqlite3.so` exists , delete it and re-create it :

```
cd /usr/lib
rm libsqlite3.so
ln -s libsqlite.so.0 libsqlite3.so
```

That's all...

Answer (score 0):

I found that installing the classicclient does not take into account the fact that in case of a 64bit system, the linked file for libsqlite3.so is in a different location.

Instead of linking to /usr/lib/libsqlite.so.0 , you will have to create a link to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0:

```
cd /usr/lib
rm libsqlite3.so
ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 libsqlite3.so
```